# How to locate figures with x,y specified location in a presentation

Tags: positioning

I want to fix my figure in slide (latex frame) as per my wish with x,y position specification.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could use the [`textpos`](http://ctan.org/pkg/textpos) package for absolute positioning of figures or text boxes.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
  \setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
  \setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
   \begin{textblock}{20}(40,20)
      \includegraphics{file}
    \end{textblock}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

with the syntax `\begin{textblock}{*width*}(*x-position,y-position*)`

Comment: \begin{picture}(50,50)
\put(250,0){\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figs/set}}}
\end{picture} This works simply to locate picture... Kindly give your suggestion over this code with your code.

Comment: @PalaniKannan: good! You could make an answer from that code in your comment.

Comment: @PalaniKannan: with `textpos` you could use a grid, relative positioning, and positioning on the background, For a simple single placement a `picture` environment is also fine.

Comment: with this solution I could only place one image in the document, the second would not appear

Answer (score 17):

As far as I remember,

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

...

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.south west)+(2cm,5cm)$) {
     \includegraphics{imgfile}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

should place `imgfile.pdf` at x=2cm and y=5cm from the lower left page corner.

Comment: A more convenient and flexible macro for absolute positioning is given here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/311031 .

Comment: When I run this, I get "
! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in img.png (no BoundingBox).
"

Comment: Something must be wrong with your `img.png`. Try `example-image`.

Comment: Actually the code works if I compile with pdflatex, but it doesn't if I try to compile with latex.  So presumably the issue is not with the image file.

Answer (score 15):

As suggested by @PalaniKannan you could do the following:

```
\begin{picture}(50,50)
\put(200,-300){\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{file}}}
\end{picture}
```

This will place the image at position "200 right and 300 down" relative to the top left corner of the current page.

Also have a look at [this wiki page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Picture).

Comment: I'd rather recommend `{50,100}` for the start position and `[width=0.66\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,keepaspectratio]` for the scaling, but the picture environment is the way to go for simple things.

Comment: This code is useless for absolute positioning, because the `picture` environment is placed at the *current* position.

Comment: @AlexG it can work for uses by putting it as the first command in the slide and using a size `(0,0)` environment (so that it does not move stuff coming after it). The actual size is then set by `\includegraphics` and the position by `\put`.
I used this before the `\titlepage` command and it worked for me.

Comment: @fqq OP asked for *absolute* positioning, which means relative to the paper edges. In the way you suggest, even with a zero-size `picture`, `(200,-300)` would still be relative to the reference point of `picture` at the time of its use, which is, at best, the upper left corner of the text area.

Comment: Yes, I agree, indeed `(0,0)` does not put the figure in the upper left corner of the page. Your answer gives absolute positioning, this is a less reliable hack with (slightly) simpler code.