# image positioning

Tags: graphics, floats

I'm trying to put an image (test.pdf) inside an page that has already an table, the page is in landscape position.

How can I set the positioning of the image on the top right corner of the page, or at 1cm top and 1.2 cm right, even if in that position has already a portion of a cell table.

In html, like an position: `fixed; top: 10px; right:20px;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you want to achieve this in html or tex. But for tex you could use the **textpos** package as suggested here [How to locate figures with x,y specified location in a presentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32661/how-to-locate-figures-with-x-y-specified-location-in-a-presentation). Your request is achieved by:

```
\documentclass[landscape,demo]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=1cm,top=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
3&3&2\\
3&3&2\\
3&3&2\\
3&3&2\\
3&3&2\\
\end{tabular}
\begin{textblock}{600}(10,12)
\includegraphics{file}
\end{textblock}
\end{document}
```