# Change package option "overlay" from textpos package in document?

Tags: beamer, textpos

I am using the `textpos` package to position images on beamer slides. My problem is that I would like to have these images in some slides in the front of everything else (package option "overlay") and in others behind the lower bar in the beamer presentation.

Is it possible to change the package option in the document?

Comment: Can you give us a MWE to play with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality should appear in textpos v1.8.  That's not yet released, because I haven't yet had the time to tidy up the docs, but until it is released and included in distributions, you can have a try with [v1.8b1](https://nxg.me.uk/dist/textpos/textpos-1.8b1.tar.gz).  Any problems, [do shout](https://bitbucket.org/nxg/textpos/issues?status=new&status=open).

Comment: Thanks. Any idea when it will be available? Also, how can I install the beta without "disturbing" the TeX Live installation?

Comment: I don't want to make any promises about when it'll be available (but this exchange encourages me to think about doing that soon). To use this, unpack the tarball (`tar xzf textpos-1.8b1.tar.gz`), run `latex textpos.ins` which will generate `textpos.sty`, then either put that file in the same directory as your source, or put it in some directory `foo` and set `TEXINPUTS=foo:` (note colon!) to tell LaTeX where to find it. (hmm: there _must_ be a good answer about this process on this site somewhere, but if there is I can't find it!).

Comment: ...and see [this list of installation pointers](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2426/96)

Comment: @Rainer v1.8 is now released and [at CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos)

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `textpos`, the TikZ-way of absolute positioning could be used via the convenience command `\placetextbox` as defined in the example below. It is straightforward to be used;  the  ***z***-**level** of the typeset material is determined by the order of its usage:

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe} % example images
\usepackage{lipsum} % example text

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% absolute positioning of typeset material    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\placetextbox}[4][center]{%
  % [#1]: box anchor: center (default) | 
  %                 south west | west | north west | north |
  %                 north east | east | south east | south | 
  %                 mid west | mid | mid east |
  %                 base west | base | base east 
  % #2: horizontal position (fraction of page width)
  % #3: vertical position (fraction of page height)
  % #4: content
  %
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay,x=\paperwidth,y=\paperheight]{%
    \node[anchor=#1,inner sep=0pt]
    at ($(current page.south west)+(#2,#3)$) {#4};
  }%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \placetextbox[north west]{0}{1}{\includegraphics[width=0.6\paperwidth]{example-image-a}}
  %normal text
  \lipsum[1]
  \placetextbox[south east]{1}{0}{\includegraphics[width=0.6\paperwidth]{example-image-b}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks - tikz is definitely an option and I will keep it in mind. Special thanks for the nice command ```\placetextbox``` which makes using ```tikz``` for this purpose much easier!