# Replicate the title of this CV: \colorbox outside the margins and words of the same length

Tags: titles, cv

I would like to replicate the title "Katie Smalls" of [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Sample/Curriculum-Vitae) CV

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[]{xcolor}
\usepackage[top=0cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\centering
\colorbox{pink}{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \vspace{3cm}
    \textcolor{white}{\Huge \textbf{KATIE}}\\
    \textcolor{white}{\Huge \textbf{SMALLS}}
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are three main problems with this attempt:

- I need a top margin in the rest of the document, so `top=0cm` have to be changed
- There's still a white space at the top of the document
- Name and surname are not alligned

Comment: Why do you use the article class (`\documentclass{article}`) for a CV ? A lot of packages are specially designed for CV ...

Comment: @JérômeDequeker I want to replicate the title of this CV, but then I want to use it in another document, not a CV.

Comment: @ebo Thank you for your suggestion: what is more important to me is the creation of that `\colorbox`, let's say, outside the margins

Comment: @Andrea : so you could have a look at [How to locate figures with x,y specified location in a presentation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32671/64454)

Comment: @ebo Some problems with  [How to locate figures with x,y specified location in a presentation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32661/how-to-locate-figures-with-x-y-specified-location-in-a-presentation/32671#32671): I can't use `\documentclass[demo]{beamer}`, and the solution with `tikz` seems even more complicated

Comment: @ebo: Sorry I didn't know the `beamer `class before and the related controls. It works. Now remain how to allign the two words.

Comment: See (and wait!) [“BigText” formating: how to adapt the fontsize to make all lines have the same width?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/316964/64454) (-;

Answer (score 2):

The TikZ-based method can be wrapped into a macro as shown here:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/311031 .

The given macro allows the specification of an anchor point of the box and uses fractions of the page dimensions for accurate positioning. There is no need for setting margins or additional calculations.

[image]

Your example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% absolute positioning of typeset material    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\placetextbox}[4][center]{%
  % [#1]: box anchor: center (default) | 
  %                 south west | west | north west | north |
  %                 north east | east | south east | south | 
  %                 mid west | mid | mid east |
  %                 base west | base | base east 
  % #2: horizontal position (fraction of page width)
  % #3: vertical position (fraction of page height)
  % #4: content
  %
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay,x=\paperwidth,y=\paperheight]{%
    \node[anchor=#1,inner sep=0pt]
      at ($(current page.south west)+(#2,#3)$) {#4};
  }%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\placetextbox[north]{0.5}{1.0}{%
  \colorbox{pink}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t][0.3\textwidth][b]{0.3\textwidth}
      \sffamily
      \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\textcolor{white}{\Huge \textbf{KATIE}}}\\[0.5ex]
      \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\textcolor{white}{\Huge \textbf{SMALLS}}}
    \end{minipage}}%
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution, using `\raisebox`, `resizebox` and the optional parameter `height` of `\parbox`. The trick is to declare to `\raisebox` that the `\parbox` has height 0:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{gillius2} 
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[showframe, top = 3cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \raisebox{\dimexpr 3cm + 7pt\relax}[0pt]{\colorbox{HotPink2!90!OrangeRed1}
    {\parbox[t][4.5cm][c]{0.3\textwidth}
        {\centering\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\Huge\vskip1.2cm
    \resizebox{0.25\textwidth}{!}{KATIE}\\[-0.5ex]
    \resizebox{0.25\textwidth}{!}{SMALLS}}}
    }
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved the first two problems:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{textblock}{130}(30,0)
  \colorbox{pink}{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \vspace{3cm}
        \textcolor{white}{\Huge \textbf{KATIE}}\\
        \textcolor{white}{\Huge \textbf{SMALLS}}
    \end{minipage}}
\end{textblock}

\end{document}
```

Thanks to [ebo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/64454/ebo) for all the help!