# "BigText" formating: how to adapt the fontsize to make all lines have the same width?

Tags: formatting, fontsize

As in [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30384835), I want to replicate the so-called 'big text' formatting:

[image]

### Functioning:

1. You give as input:

   - the line (column) width for each line,
   - and the content of each line.
2. The font size is dynamically adapted for each line so that they all have the same width.

(Note that, in previous example, each line is only one word long. However, I would like to be able to have longer lines (in terms of words number) as in [this example](https://www.posterhaste.com/media/item-type-files/big-text-print/YWC4Ah.jpg.2000x2000_q85.jpg).)

**Question:** how to achieve this formatting with LaTeX?

---

### Partial/not satisfactory solutions (so far):

- Of course, justified text is not satisfactory, since it adapt the line length by modulating the character and/or interword spacing... and not the font size.
- [Fit text into given box by adjusting the fontsize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26002/64454) develops a solution, but is rather a "maximum" constraint (it won't makes the text bigger to fill all the space).

---

### Edit:

What makes this formatting visually strong is that the very first/last pixel of each line are aligned (or in other words: there is no kerning nor protrusion)<sup>*</sup>. In suggested answers however, their is a protrusion that is especially noticeable at the beginning of the last two lines.

[image]

So, **is it be possible to 'pixel-align' the beginning and the end of each line?** (if yes, how?!)

<sub>*to be honest, I observed that there is a small protrusion in the given example. But it is less noticeable than in suggested answer, and I'd like to be able to have no protrusion at all.</sub>

Comment: I've selected ***[egreg's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/317012/64454)***, since it **handles side-bearing** adjustment, and get more used to **`LaTeX3`-syntax**. However, it needs to be compiled with **`XeLaTeX`**. Thus, I suggest you to also have a look to the also [satisfactory ***solution written by Runar Trollet***](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316977/64454) that is a bit **easier to implement** (imho) and **requires `LaTeX` only**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An implementation with `expl3` for a cleaner syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\bigtext}{mm}
 { % #1 = width, #2 = text, with \\ to separate lines
  \ebo_bigtext:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_ebo_bigtext_text_seq
\box_new:N \l_ebo_bigtext_line_box

\cs_new_protected:Nn \ebo_bigtext:nn
 {
  \begin{minipage}{#1}
  \baselineskip=-\maxdimen \lineskip=4pt
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_ebo_bigtext_text_seq { \\ } { #2 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_ebo_bigtext_text_seq
   {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_ebo_bigtext_line_box { ##1 }
    \box_resize_to_wd:Nn \l_ebo_bigtext_line_box { \textwidth }
    \box_use:N \l_ebo_bigtext_line_box
   }
  \end{minipage}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent
\bigtext{15em}{SOME \\ TOTALLY \\ HIPSTER \\ QUOTE \\ ABOUT \\ LIFE}
\quad
\sffamily
\bigtext{15em}{SOME \\ TOTALLY \\ HIPSTER \\ QUOTE \\ ABOUT \\ LIFE}

\end{document}
```

Spaces around `\\` are ignored.

[image]

One might add an optional argument to set the vertical space between lines, in the macros above set to 3pt.

---

With XeLaTeX, but it needs a further refinement for the case when the line has a single letter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\bigtext}{mm}
 { % #1 = width, #2 = text, with \\ to separate lines
  \ebo_bigtext:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_ebo_bigtext_text_seq
\box_new:N \l_ebo_bigtext_line_box
\tl_new:N \l_ebo_bigtext_line_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \ebo_bigtext:nn
 {
  \begin{minipage}{#1}
  \baselineskip=-\maxdimen \lineskip=4pt
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_ebo_bigtext_text_seq { \\ } { #2 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_ebo_bigtext_text_seq
   {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_ebo_bigtext_line_box { \ebo_bigtext_remsb:n { ##1 } }
    \box_resize_to_wd:Nn \l_ebo_bigtext_line_box { \textwidth }
    \box_use:N \l_ebo_bigtext_line_box
   }
  \end{minipage}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \ebo_bigtext_remsb:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_ebo_bigtext_line_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \A(.) } { \c{ebo_kleft:n}\cB\{\1\cE\} } \l_ebo_bigtext_line_tl
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { (.)\Z } { \c{ebo_kright:n}\cB\{\1\cE\} } \l_ebo_bigtext_line_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_ebo_bigtext_line_tl
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \ebo_kleft:n
 {
  \kern-\XeTeXglyphbounds1~\the\XeTeXcharglyph`#1 #1
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \ebo_kright:n
 {
  #1\kern-\XeTeXglyphbounds3~\the\XeTeXcharglyph`#1
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent
\bigtext{15em}{SOME \\ TOTALLY \\ HIPSTER \\ QUOTE \\ ABOUT \\ LIFE}
\quad
\sffamily
\bigtext{15em}{SOME \\ TOTALLY \\ HIPSTER \\ QUOTE \\ ABOUT \\ LIFE}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ebo What you call “protrusion” is just how characters are designed; some have side-bearings, some haven't. You clearly see that the sans-serif L in my example has a side-bearing. You can remove them with XeTeX (only using OpenType/TrueType fonts).

Comment: Indeed, *side-bearing* is the term: I'll have a look at [Precision copyfitting in xcoffin](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34563/precision-copyfitting-in-xcoffin) that you helped to solve!

Comment: @ebo That's what I seemed to remember.

Comment: It works when you define ``\def\kright#1{\leavevmode #1\kern-\XeTeXglyphbounds3 \the\XeTeXcharglyph`#1 }`` and 
 ``\def\kleft#1{\leavevmode \kern-\XeTeXglyphbounds1 \the\XeTeXcharglyph`#1 #1}`` (outside `ExplSyntax`) and adapt manually all the words, like `\kleft{A}BOU\kright{T} \\ \kleft{L}IF\kright{E}` (of course, you need to compile with `xelatex`). Thx! However, I've no time now to automate this solution...

Comment: @ebo Done; don't try the code with a single letter in a line

Comment: This might be overkill, but is it possible to get some middleway between these two settings? I think it gives the illusion of not being straight anymore.

Comment: @RunarTrollet You may try with 0.5 in front of `\XeTeXglyphbounds`

Answer (score 13):

Here is a solution using `adjustbox` The vertical spacing between lines could be altered a bit, and the syntax could probably need some approvements.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{helvet}

\definecolor{Pink}{HTML}{E22E3B}
\definecolor{Blue}{HTML}{0C2153}
\definecolor{DarkBlue}{HTML}{0C1C3B}
\definecolor{Red}{HTML}{C51E1F}

\setlength{\fboxrule}{4pt}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}

\newcommand{\BigWords}[1]{%
        \adjustboxset{min width=\linewidth, margin*=0.2em 1ex 0ex 0ex}%
        \foreach \i [count=\ni] in {#1}{%
                \ifnum\ni=1    
                        \adjustbox{}{\i}%
                \else
                        \\\adjustbox{}{\i}%
                \fi
        }\vspace{-1ex}%
}
\begin{document}
\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{15cm}
    \bfseries\sffamily
    \BigWords{SOME,TOTALLY,HIPSTER,QUOTE,ABOUT,LIFE}%
    \end{minipage}%
}%
\hspace{2em}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5pt}%
\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{20cm}
    \bfseries\sffamily
    \BigWords{
    \textcolor{Pink}{RUN},
    \textcolor{Blue}{LIKE},
    \textcolor{DarkBlue}{RYAN},
    \textcolor{Red}{GOSLING},
    \textcolor{Pink}{IS WAITING},
    \textcolor{Blue}{FOR YOU},
    \textcolor{DarkBlue}{AT THE},
    \textcolor{Red}{FINISH LINE},
    \textcolor{Pink}{(WITH A PUPPY)}%
    }%
    \end{minipage}%
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have several useless `%` characters, but miss some in important places.

Comment: @egreg I believe it is better now, thank you for pointing it out :)

Comment: Yes, I removed some (not really important) and added a couple (important). `;-)`

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I've edited my question based on your results with a refinement about kerning. I'm trying to figure out how to disable protrusion, but if you feel like it, do not hesitate to update your answer (-;

Answer (score 5):

Here's one option, just using `resizebox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\newlength\foo
\setlength\foo{15em}
\noindent
\resizebox{\foo}{!}{SOME}\\
\resizebox{\foo}{!}{TOTALLY}\\
\resizebox{\foo}{!}{HIPSTER}\\
\resizebox{\foo}{!}{QUOTE}\\
\resizebox{\foo}{!}{ABOUT}\\
\resizebox{\foo}{!}{LIFE}\\
\end{document}
```

It's inelegant and cumbersome. But it's a proof of concept. This could be combined with the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25611/215) for a more automatic solution.