# TikZ: remove side-bearing from text node

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, nodes, tikz-styles

I want to horizontally align the first letter of a text node with a shape I've drawn.
 In my example, I want the `F` to be horizontally pixel-aligned with the left side of the square.

The first step is to use `inner sep = 0pt` as option. However, because of side-bearing, the first letter might still not be perfectly aligned as it is the case in the example below. 
"Of course", I'd like an automatic solution -- i.e. that do not require manual tuning (that already know how to do).

[image]

In [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/317012/64454) for [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/316964/64454), egreg show me how to use `XeLaTeX` to remove side bearings. However, since my picture is for a paper and its editor only accepts `pdfLaTeX` compiling, his solution cannot be used here.

---

### MWE

(`draw, help lines` options in the code are for debugging purpose only)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{helvet}
    \usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill (-1.1,0) rectangle (-.1,1);
        \node [inner sep = 0pt, font=\sffamily, anchor = west] at (-1.1,1.25) {Ftest};

        \fill (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        \node [inner sep = 0pt, draw, very thin, font=\sffamily, anchor = west] at (0,1.25) {Ftest};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: pdftex has no information about the character other than four lengths height, depth, width, italic correction, it may be a black square or a white rectangle or look like an F so there is no way to avoid giving tex the corrections by hand, either on each instance or setting up a font-specific table of spacing corrections for each character.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle well... it is not what I expected, but it does answer my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pdftex has no information about the character other than four lengths height, depth, width, italic correction, it may be a black square or a white rectangle or look like an F so there is no way to avoid giving tex the corrections by hand, either on each instance or setting up a font-specific table of spacing corrections for each character